# Limiting entries per person on facebook app

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I am developing a facebook app that is a basic competition. Is there a way to limit each user's entry to X amount of times based on their facebook ID.

Ideally, this would be without 'Allowing' the app but if that is the only way it may be an option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reliable way would be to record the user's Facebook ID alongside their entry, but gaining access to that data does, indeed, require the user to log in to ('allow') the app.

Otherwise, you're back to registering entries against other (personally unique) data you ask the user to submit (email address, for example).

Comment: Is there a way to record their entry client side?

Comment: You can use sessions/cookies to record number of entries made already. But of course its easy to circumvent that.

As marramgrass says, you need to record something uniquely identifiable (which you need anyway in order to know who has entered the competition, right?) and then check if they have already entered.